# How to enable/disable textfield on checkbox value change in apache wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I have an html form containing a check box & a ListView containing some text fields. On checking the checkbox i want the textfields to be disabled & vice versa.

I am using checkbox with AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior. But its not setting the textfields as enabled/disabled. Below is the code snippet -

```
Checkbox.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            listView.setEnabled(!Checkbox.getModelObject());
            listViewContainer.addOrReplace(listView);
            listViewContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            target.addComponent(listViewContainer);
        }
    });
```

HTML is -

```
<form wicket:id="geoForm">
      Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="unmanagedChk" />
        <div id="listViewContainer" wicket:id="listViewContainerId">
            <div wicket:id="customGeoForChannel">         
                <div>
                    Latitude(decimal):
                    <input type="text" wicket:id="lat" maxlength="18" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    Longitude(decimal):
                    <input type="text" wicket:id="lon" maxlength="19" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    Radius(miles):
                    <input type="text" wicket:id="radius" maxlength="3" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </form>
```

geoForm --- Form

customGeoForChannel --- ListView

lat, lon, radius --- textfields

unmanagedChk --- checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Your listViewContainer has to write out its markup id *before* you update it via ajax. Do this immediately when you construct it!

```
listViewContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

BTW the following is superfluous, since the listView is already contained in the component tree (at least I hope you added it already):

```
listViewContainer.addOrReplace(listView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the listviewcontainer to the form & added the form to the target as below. This solved the issue.

```
protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            listView.setEnabled(!Checkbox.getModelObject());
            listViewContainer.addOrReplace(listView);
            listViewContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            target.addComponent(listViewContainer);
            form.add(listViewContainer);
            target.addComponent(form);
        }
```